# Visual studio for mac open solution as empty

Tags: macos, visual-studio, solution

I have a solution that created by visual studio 2012, now i want to open it with visual studio for mac, but it opens that solution as an empty solution and does not show solution files and i got this error:

**Projects with non-local resource (`http://...`) not supported**

how can i solve it?